# Address a column with the variable value of another column in the same row using the pipe operator

Tags: r, dplyr, pipe

An example data.frame:

```
library(tidyverse)
example <- data.frame(matrix(sample.int(15),5,3),
                      sample(c("A","B","C"),5,replace=TRUE) ) %>%
                      `colnames<-`( c("A","B","C","choose") ) %>% print()
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C choose
1  9 12  4      A
2  7  8 13      C
3  5  1  2      A
4 15  3 11      C
5 14  6 10      B
```

The column "choose" indicates which value should be selected from the columns A,B,C

My humble solution for the column "result" :

```
cols <- c(A=1,B=2,C=3)
col_index <- cols[example$choose]
xy <- cbind(1:nrow(example),col_index)
example %>% mutate(result = example[xy])
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C choose result
1  9 12  4      A      9
2  7  8 13      C     13
3  5  1  2      A      5
4 15  3 11      C     11
5 14  6 10      B      6
```

I'am sure there is a more elegant solution with dplyr,
but my attemps with "rowwise" or "accross" failed.

Is it possible to get here a one-line-solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The efficient option is to make use of row/column indexing

```
example$result <- example[1:3][cbind(seq_len(nrow(example)), 
          match(example$choose, names(example)))]
```

---

with `dplyr`, we may use `get` with `rowwise`

```
library(dplyr)
example %>%
    rowwise %>%
    mutate(result = get(choose)) %>%
    ungroup
```

Or instead of `get` use `cur_data()`

```
example %>% 
   rowwise %>%
   mutate(result = cur_data()[[choose]]) %>%
   ungroup
```

---

Or the vectorized option with row/column indexing

```
example %>% 
   mutate(result = select(., where(is.numeric))[cbind(row_number(), 
       match(choose, names(example)))])
```

Comment: Thank you for that bunch of solutions. Most astonishing to me is the use of the _get()_ function from the r-base-package in this context, which simplifies the code dramatically.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative way:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

example %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    -choose,
  ) %>% 
  filter(choose == name) %>% 
  select(result=value) %>% 
  bind_cols(example)
```

```
  result     A     B     C choose
   <int> <int> <int> <int> <chr> 
1      9     6     9     1 B     
2     14     5     2    14 C     
3      7     8     7     3 B     
4     15    15     4    12 A     
5     11    13    10    11 C
```

Comment: Thank you for that unusual solution. Indeed, the _pivot_longer_ opens another view of the table-handling.